# Pythonでcsvファイル内の特定の列だけ結合がしたい

Tags: python, csv

初心者で質問の仕方が悪いかもしれませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

csvファイルをPythonで特定の列だけ結合したいです。1枚目のスクショのように「姓」と「名」のセルが分かれていますが、2枚目のように「姓名」のように結合させてその下のセルも自動で結合する方法を教えていただきたいです。
スクショは2行しかないですが、何十行、何百行も増えるので自動で姓と名をくっつけてくれるやり方を教えていただけたら幸いです。

結合後の姓と名の間は半角でも全角でもどちらでも大丈夫です。

[image: 変更前]

[image: 変更後]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./offerlist.csv', encoding='cp932')
df2 = df[["メールアドレス", "姓", "名", "住所"]]
print(df2)
df2.to_csv('./output.csv',header=True,index=False)
```

よろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: CSVファイルであるなら, エクセルらしきソフトで開いてハードコピーするのではなく, テキストエディターなどで開いて テキストで示したほうがよいでしょう。混乱の元になります

Comment: こちらもどうぞ [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

以下のように単純に列を足しあわせればよいと思います。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'メール':['a@example.com','b@example.com'],'姓':['tanaka','sato'],'名':['taro','hanako'],'値':[1,2]})
df['姓名'] = df['姓'] + ' ' + df['名']
df = df[['メール','姓名','値']]
print(df)
#             メール           姓名  値
#0  a@example.com  tanaka taro  1
#1  b@example.com  sato hanako  2
```

Comment: 質問の仕方が悪かったです…行の要素はこれから何行も増えていくので増えても自動でセル同士をくっつけてくれる方法を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 列を足し合わせているだけなので、何行あってもよいです。

Answer (score 0):

Excelでセル結合するには`merge_cells`を使います。
セル結合したセルには左端のセルの内容が設定されますので、結合前のセルの内容を取っておいて、セル結合したセルに結合した内容を設定する必要があります。

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('セル結合前.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    v1 = row[1].value   #結合前のB列の値
    v2 = row[2].value   #結合前のC列の値
    row_no = str(row[0].row)    #行番号
    cells = 'B' + row_no + ':' + 'C' + row_no
    ws.merge_cells(cells)   #セル結合
    row[1].value = v1 + ' ' + v2    #セル結合したセルに結合した値を書き戻す
wb.save('セル結合後.xlsx')
```

Comment: csvファイルをxlsxに変更する必要があるということでしょうか？

Comment: セル結合が必要でなければ不要です。CSVではセル結合できないです。

Comment: csvではできないんですか！ありがとうございます！

Comment: ExcelでCSVファイルを開いてセル結合しても、CSVファイルとして保存するとセル結合はなかったことになります。他の回答のとおりCSVでも値の結合？はできます。